# Tweepy api.list_direct_messages() updates slowly

Tags: python, tweepy

Hello and thanks for taking the time to try to answer my question.  I'll be as blunt, and specific as possible.

Using tweepy I'm trying to get the ID from the last message in my DMs by using this method

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(token[0], token[1])
auth.set_access_token(token[2], token[3])
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify= True)


last_dm = api.list_direct_messages(1)

for messages in last_dm:
    print(messages.message_create['sender_id'])
    if not (messages.message_create['sender_id'] == my_id):
          send_message()
```

This works as expected, however something weird happens right after.  If I were to run this program once it'd work, but if I run it again within 3 or so minutes it won't register that the sender ID has changed.  Any time after that it'll work however so I think theres some sort of lag coming from tweepy.

My question is is there a way around this?  If not for tweepy what about with another library or language like Java script?

Comment: Can you post the code where you create API connection object?

Comment: I added it to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rate max limit for all APIs calls to Twitter, with Tweepy you can let the library deal with it setting `wait_on_rate_limit=True`.
In this case Tweepy will slow down (hold the requests) to stay within the limits with the advantage that you will not get an error/exception in the application.

In a similar implementation I am calling the `api.list_direct_messages` once every 60 seconds and I don't hit the rate limit (obviously I cannot respond in real time but this is a decision which depends on the context and business logic).